# how to convert the double qoute to backtick

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a message string with a dynamic variable.

```
var name="venkat";
var message ="hello ${name}"
```

but this does not works, so i use backtick to achieve this

```
var name="venkat";
var message =`hello ${name}`
```

My question is there is any way to covert "" => ``

Comment: actually sorry for my mistake i want to done this in nodejs instead of dart can any one help me with that

Answer (score 1):

When not accessing object properties, you should simply use the dollar sign, without the brackets:

```
String name = "venkat";
String message = "Hello $name";
```

For accessing an object property:

```
Person newPerson = Person(name: "venkat");
String message = "Hello ${newPerson.name}";
```

---

Or do you have other reasons why you want to programmatically swap double quotes for backticks?

---

https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_string_interpolations.html

[image: String interpolation]

Answer (score 0):

Try escape \ will works.

```
var message ="\`hello ${name}\`"
```